# ASP.Net MVC Modelbinder bind to nested property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to handle various Model creations in one View / Action.

When s/o clicks on "New Computer" the Type ViewModel receives a new object of type Computer. The View switches through the different types (in this case Computer) and creates the View based on the passed in model.
This worked fine but when submitting the form (calling the CreateComputer Action) not the whole Computer-object gets transmitted - to be precise the Computer-related properties (the both enums) gets lost. I think this is because the Name of the dropdown's do not start with Hardware, but are called "FormType" and "PerformanceType" instead, is there any proper solution for this case?

**Clarification:**

The Model "Computer" inherits from "Hardware". Because I'd like to handle all creations, updates etc. with one VM / View the ViewModel has a Property called Hardware of type Hardware. Unfortunately when using the VM as Action parameter the property Hardware is always of type Hardware (although sometimes it should be of type Computer). Additionally, my approach works (partially) - the modelbinder seems to be smart enough to bind to the nested type Hardware.

What do I want?

In the Action I want the Method to be able to determine if the passed in parameter is of type Hardware or of type Computer (inherits form Hardware) and let the Controller do it's stuff for the determined model. In other words: I want to avoid to create different Actions for different Models such as "CreateComputer(Computer computer)" and "CreateGeneric(Hardware hardware)".

**Models:**

Computer:

```
namespace UserChange.com.Models
{
public class Computer : Hardware
    {
        public PerformanceType PerformanceType { get; set; }
        public FormType FormType { get; set; }

        public override HardwareType GetHardwareType()
        {
            return HardwareType.Computer;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Computer: {base.ToString()}";
        }
    }
}
```

Monitor:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace UserChange.com.Models
{
    public class Monitor : Hardware
    {
        [Required]
        public short Size { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public MonitorColor MonitorColor { get; set; }

        public override HardwareType GetHardwareType()
        {
            return HardwareType.Monitor;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Monitor: " + base.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Hardware:

```
 [Table("NEOV_Hardware")]
public class Hardware : BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    public virtual HardwareType GetHardwareType()
    {
        return HardwareType.Generic;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Description;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateComputer(Computer hardware)
{
    var uow = new UnitOfWork(new ApplicationContext());
    uow.HardwareRepository.Add(hardware);
    uow.Save();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

View:

```
@using UserChange.com.Models
@using UserChange.dal.Repository.Interface
@model UserChange.ViewModels.NewHardwareViewModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@{
    switch (Model.Hardware.GetHardwareType()) {
        case HardwareType.Computer:
            <h2>New Computer</h2>
            using (Html.BeginForm("CreateComputer", "Hardware", FormMethod.Post)) {
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Model name:</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Hardware.Description)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Form factor:</td>
                        <td>@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(o => (o.Hardware as Computer).FormType)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Performance type:</td>
                        <td>@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(o => (o.Hardware as Computer).PerformanceType)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Comment:</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(o => o.Hardware.Comment)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            }
            break;
        case HardwareType.Monitor:
            <h2>New Monitor</h2>
            using (Html.BeginForm("CreateMonitor", "Hardware", FormMethod.Post)) {
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Model name:</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Hardware.Description)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size:</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o => (o.Hardware as Monitor).Size)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Color:</td>
                        <td>@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(o => (o.Hardware as Monitor).MonitorColor)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Comment:</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(o => o.Hardware.Comment)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            }
            break;
        case HardwareType.Generic:
            <h2>New Generic device</h2>
            using (Html.BeginForm("CreateGeneric", "Hardware", FormMethod.Post)) {
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Model name:</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Hardware.Description)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Comment:</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(o => o.Hardware.Comment)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

** Edit 1: ** - Missing VM

```
public class NewHardwareViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public Hardware Hardware { get; set; }
        public NewHardwareViewModel(Hardware hardware, bool isUserAuthorized) : base(isUserAuthorized)
        {
            Hardware = hardware;
        }

        public NewHardwareViewModel(){ }
    }
```

Comment: Unclear what your trying to do (other than to say your approach will not work). The model in your view is `NewHardwareViewModel` so the parameter in the POST method should also be `NewHardwareViewModel` (and yor have not even shown that model). And the correct `name` attributes for model binding will not be generated for the enums because of the casting in the view (using `(o.Hardware as Computer)` )

Comment: I've added some clarification - I hope this will help..

Comment: Then you will be writing far more code to write your own custom model binder to make it work.

Comment: So creating a separate View and ViewModel for each Model (even if they are "related" -is the common solution for this type of problem?

Comment: You will find it simpler :)

Comment: I hope this means u're writing an answer otherwise I have to admit that I don't understand your last comment :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126079/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-c4p741nz).